# Cannot find module in Angular routing

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

My folder structure is:

```
+-- app.module.ts
+-- app.routing.ts
+-- app.component.ts
+-- account/
|   +-- account.module.ts
|   +-- account.routing.ts
|   +-- account.component.ts
```

In my app.routing.ts I have,

```
  { path: 'account', loadChildren: './account/account.module#AccountModule' },
```

And, in account.routing.ts, I have,

```
  { path: 'login', component: LoginFormComponent}
```

but when I enter page/account/login I get the following error:

> NodeInvocationException: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find
>   module './account/account.module'. Error: Cannot find module
>   './account/account.module'.

I've tried changing ./account/account.module#AccountModule to app/account/account.module#AccountModule, same error.

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `/app/account/account.module#AccountModule` ? Relative paths in Angular causes strange unexpected results all the freaking time.

Comment: @I.R.R. no success :(

Comment: How about other parts of your code? Where is the promise getting it's data? I once had to spend two days on a very very similar problem because I did not put two dots (..) and a slash (/) in front of my API endpoint, just to give you an idea on the kind of debugging you can expect with this paths problem.

Comment: Can you show AccountModule code? Have to tried eager loading? if yes, did that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your account module sould have a single route like below

code for routing which will be routed once the module is lazy loaded

```
const routes: Routes = [{
  path: ':something',
  component: AccountComponent,
}];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AccountRoutingModule {
}
```

Calling the routing module in core module

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    AccountRoutingModule,
    ...
```

Comment: Looking at his setup, looks like he's trying to do lazy loading. This solution will make it eager load.

Answer (score 14):

you can try changing

```
  { path: 'account', loadChildren: './account/account.module#AccountModule' }
```

to

```
import {AccountModule} from './path';

{ path: 'account', loadChildren: ()=> AccountModule' }
```

**note** - do not forget to import module as above

Comment: it should be the correct answer. My code not work with the first way: { path: 'account', loadChildren: './account/account.module#AccountModule' }

Comment: I don't know why the original method of implementing loadChildren isn't working, but this did solve the issue for me.

Comment: I expect symbolic link/junction or parent path with spaces might be an issue. Original works for colleague but not for me (And I use ntfs junction with path containing spaces).

Comment: That solved my problem. But I don't understand: how the hell did you get that idea? I would never have thought about that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**The string version of `loadChildren` has been deprecated in angular 8**

See: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#800-2019-05-28
See: https://angular.io/api/router/LoadChildren

**New syntax in angular 8/9**

The new syntax takes a **dynamic import expression**. This is a function that returns an import. It is critical that you import your module there. Otherwise you are not lazy loading the module, but eagerly loading it.

```
{ 
path: 'account', 
loadChildren: ()=> import('./account/account.module').next(mod => mod.AccountModule) 
}
```

The docs: https://angular.io/api/router/LoadChildrenCallback

**New syntax in angular 10**

In angular 10 the syntax slightly changed again. Now it provides the import as a result of a JavaScript Promise ( [import returns a Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Dynamic_Imports): ):

```
{ 
path: 'account', 
loadChildren: ()=> import('./account/account.module').then(mod => mod.AccountModule) 
}
```

**Warning: Assigning a module after importing will not lazy load your module!**

S.Pradeep's solution will still eagerly load the module! You can check for yourself by implementing both approaches while checking the new (lazy loaded) network request navigating to a lazy loaded path.

Comment: This solution work well in Angular10.  Old way:  { path: 'account', loadChildren: './account/account.module#AccountModule' } is work in Angular 6.

Comment: In Angular10, change a little bit as: { 
path: 'account', 
loadChildren: ()=> import('./account/account.module').then(mod => mod.AccountModule) 
}

Comment: @ChinaHelloWorld Thx for the comment! I updated the answer to also provide angular 10's syntax ;).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, i tried couple of things. But changing **app.routing.ts** does the trick.

just replace your line with :

```
{ path: 'account', loadChildren: () => AccountModule },
```

I hope it helps